# Python Flask cannot insert data into Mysql

Tags: python, mysql, flask

This is the form in my html

```
<form class="user" style="margin:auto; background-color:white;border:3px #2d2e33 dashed;" method="POST" action="{{ url_for('addnew') }}">
    <div style="text-align: center"> <h3>新增人員</h3></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0" style="">
            <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                <h4>編號：<input required type="text"  class="form-control form-control-user" name="emplo_num" style="width:500px;height:10px" /></h4>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4>姓名：<input required type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" name="emplo_nam"  style="width:500px;height:10px" /></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                <h4 >信箱：<input required type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" name="emplo_email" style="width:500px;height:10px"/ ></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                <h4 >密碼：<input required type="text"  class="form-control form-control-user" name="emplo_pass" style="width:500px;height:10px"/></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                <h4 >部門：<input required type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" name="emplo_dep" style="width:500px;height:10px" /></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                <h4 >權限：<input required type="text"  class="form-control form-control-user" name="emplo_auth" style="width:500px;height:10px" /></h4>
            </div>
            <div  class="form-group" style="text-align:center">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="fa-solid fa-user-plus" style="color :white;border:white;border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;background-color:#0D2440;width:80px;height:26px" >
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

This is my python code and I use the way python connect Mysql

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',           # 連線主機名稱
    user='root',                # 登入帳號
    password='888888',
    port='3307'                 # 登入密碼
)

app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
app.config['SESSION_PERMANENT'] = True
app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME'] = timedelta(days=1)
Session(app)

@app.route('/addnew.html', methods=['GET','POST'])
def addnew():
    input =cgi.FieldStorage()
    if input:
        emplo_num=input.getvalue('emplo_num')
        emplo_nam=input.getvalue('emplo_nam')
        emplo_email=input.getvalue('emplo_email')
        emplo_pass=input.getvalue('emplo_pass')
        emplo_dep=input.getvalue('emplo_dep')
        emplo_auth=input.getvalue('emplo_auth')
        cursor=conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO employ(emplo_num, emplo_nam,emplo_email,emplo_pass,emplo_dep, emplo_auth) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", (emplo_num, emplo_nam,emplo_email,emplo_pass,emplo_dep, emplo_auth))
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

    return render_template('addnew.html')
```

It is a Flask model but I use the way python connect Mysql and is successful.

The problem is I can't insert the data into Mysql and it doesn't show any error. Where is the wrong? Please give me some suggestions.Thanks for helping.

solve the problem and insert data successful.

Comment: If you are using Flask, the form data should be in `request.form` I think? I don't think it will be in a `cgi.FieldStorage` instance.

Comment: I know this is backend code but one should avoid using `input` as a variable name. I also don't think you want to `close()` the connection here.